# remove the checkbox value from the list by unchecked it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a list of `ControllModel[]` and i have list of `Action` and show then in checkbox  .

```
   export interface Controllermodel {
      controllerName:string;
      controllerDisplayName:string;
      ControllerId:string;
      actionsVM:Actionmodel[];
}

export interface Actionmodel {
      displayName:string;
      name:string;
      metaData:string;
}
```

when the checkbox is `checked` it add the value in list but i need to when the checkbox is unchecked remove value form the list .

how can i do this ??

[Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/accessmodel-t8vyoi)

in HTML :

```
    <div class="panel-body">
  <div *ngFor="let action of controller.actionsVM" class="col-auto my-1">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event,controller.controllerName,action.name)" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlAutosizing">{{action.displayName}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in ts file :

```
   onChange(event,controllerName:string,actionName:string)
{
  var test = this.PushAccessModel.find(x => x.controllerName === controllerName);
  if(test){
    test.actionsName.push({name: actionName});
  }else {
    this.PushAccessModel.push({
      controllerName: controllerName,
      actionsName: [{
        name: actionName
      }]
    });
  }

  console.log(this.PushAccessModel)
}
```

Comment: if find it, remove it using slice, not push -push add the value-. NOTE: Personally I prefer an aproach based in [ngModel] or ReactiveForms to manage a list of check-box. It's look like more "Angular" and less "JavaScript"

Comment: @Eliseo i using the slice and it solve mt problem